Let's get critical: Apr 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Chinese Language Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Is 了 optional when a time word is present?

Net Score: 7 (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


Origin of beautiful kingdom and hero kingdom

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)


What qualities does Hong Kong Mandarin have?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


"醡" and "炸" in "醡醬麵" and "炸醬麵"

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


Chengyu with two numbers

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


(Cantonese) What's the right context in which to say, "三九唔識七"?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)


How many characters do Chinese pupils know at different ages?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)


Why does 拉倒 mean "forget about it"?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)


Headline: "YouTube创始人从雅虎手中收购Delicious". What is the purpose of "手中"

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)


Is the "to" in "Let's meet from 4 _to_ five", 到？

Net Score: -3 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

